# Invalid or unspecified target for shortcut in Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, setup-project

Pretty much every time I go to build the setup project in my solution, I get the following error: "Invalid or unspecified target for shortcut".  MSDN provides [the following useless help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63a4cstk.aspx). When I go to the dialog to (re-)select the target for the shortcut:

[image]

My primary output (for my main application) is *not present*, even though it is definitely listed in the File System view:

[image]

The setup project was deleted and *completely* re-created, and checked in. When it was checked back out, I got the exact same error.

I assume that whatever reason is causing the item to not show up in the "select target" dialog, is the same reason that the build is failing in the first place. What gives?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**I just solved this by changing my build mode from Debug to Release.**

Primary Output for ... (Release x86) - **It is looking for a release build of x86.**

Comment: Yep that's what fixed it for me too. Can avoid that error by excluding the Setup project from the Debug build: right-click solution -> Configuration Manager, uncheck Build when 'Active solution configuration' dropdown is selected to Debug.

Comment: This was the problem for me too. Setting all of my items to (Active build) fixed it (after I fixed some configuration issues.)

Comment: I had a similar fix, which resulted in the following change in the Setupvdproj file:
OLD: "SourcePath" = "8:..\\FOO\\obj\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\apphost.exe"
NEW: "SourcePath" = "8:..\\FOO\\obj\\Debug\\netcoreapp3.1\\win-x86\\apphost.exe"

not sure why but the win-x86 bit was newly needed since last week.  My DevOps pipeline build didn't have any changes on my side to cause it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your Errors List you should see the error listed. Right click on it and choose the Properties Window.
Find the "Target" property and simply set it to the correct value.
This goes for the Icon problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was building and packaging a Net.Core project using a Publish Profile.

The publish was failing with no visible error during the Msi build.

I ran the publish profile manually and saw the error that I had 2 copies of appsettings.json being installed at the same location.

I excluded one of the files and both the Publish and Package completed successfully and the shortcuts became valid again.